android kotlin: Can't set multiline text in TabLayout when setIcon is used
When I set the icon of the tabLayout my text gets truncated.  I would like to have multiple line in my text. I have tried adding <item name="android:singleLine">false</item> and it does not work.
How can I force multiple lines on the text?  Do I need a custom tabLayout?  If so an example please. thank you
My XML:
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="#ffffff"
        app:tabPaddingEnd="4dp"
        app:tabPaddingStart="4dp"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabTheme"></com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>


<style name="TabTheme" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>

</style>

My Kotlin:
val sectionsPagerAdapter = SectionsPagerAdapter(this.requireActivity(), childFragmentManager)
    val viewPager: ViewPager = binding.viewPager
    viewPager.adapter = sectionsPagerAdapter

    val tabs: TabLayout = binding.tabs
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)


    //Set tab images
    tabs.getTabAt(0)?.setIcon(R.drawable.baseline_home_24)
    tabs.getTabAt(1)?.setIcon(R.drawable.baseline_view_stream_24)
    tabs.getTabAt(2)?.setIcon(R.drawable.luca___unicolor___blanco)

